# Codelite linker undefined reference error

Tags: c++, linux, codelite

I'm new to codelite and c++. I'm using Linux and the g++ compiler. I've set up a simple project with two source files just to play around with linker errors. The files look like so:

Main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

void Log(const char*);

static int Multiply (int a, int b)
{
    Log("Multiply");
    return a * b;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << Multiply(5, 8) << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Log.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

void Log(const char* message)
{
    std::cout << message << std::endl;
}
```

As you can see, Log.cpp simply specifies a function called in main. Both files are in the same directory, "src". So far all my settings are pretty much default, still I get an "undefined reference to `Log(..." error when I try to build this project.

Also, if I comment out the declaration of the Log function at the top of main.cpp, I would expect a compilation error since an undeclared function being called. Yet if I try to compile main.cpp I get no errors.

[This is what my workspace looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9LYW.png)

[Project settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0Qh1.png)

[Compiler settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZJVF.png)

[Linker settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGXuz.png)

Am I correct to expect the behaviors described above? Is there some setting I have to manually configure?

Comment: Note how Log.cpp is not being built. The search for answers starts there. I don't know this tool at all so I can't help.